# protobuf-net: where is unity folder? Or other folders listed?

Tags: unity-game-engine, protobuf-net

I just downloaded [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net), Here is the contents of 'What files do I need.txt'

```
    protobuf-net can be used on multiple platforms, and many different builds are available.

    In particular, though, there are 2 main uses:

    - the "full" version, which includes as much type-model / runtime support as will work on your chosen platform
    - the "core only" version, which includes just the fundamental reader/writer API and core objects

    If you are on a rich framework like full .NET, the "full" version is entirely appropriate and will work fine.

    However, if you are on a restricted framework (Silverlight, Phone 7, WinRT, etc) then many operations would either
    be slow, or impossible. To address this, protobuf-net provides these frameworks with a "precompile" facility,
    which moves all of the impossible / slow steps to a build-time operation, emitting a serialiation dll you
    can reference and use (now very fast etc) from your chosen framework.

    More information about the precompiler is here:
    http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/introducing-protobuf-net-precompiler.html

    protobuf-net also includes a utility for processing ".proto" files (the schema DSL used by multiple protobuf
    implementations) into C# and VB.NET; this is the ProtoGen tool.

    Neither precompile nor ProtoGen need to be deployed with your application.


    So: what do I need?

    example: running on .NET 4.0

    solution: copy the files from Full\net30. Note that protobuf-net does not require any 4.0 features, so using "net30" will
    give you all of protobuf-net including WCF support (which is the difference between "net20" and "net30").


    example: running on Silverlight 4

    option 1: copy the files from Full\sl4, and accept that it isn't quite as optimal as it could be - but perfectly fine
    for light-to-moderate serialization usage.

    option 2: copy the files from CoreOnly\sl4, and use "precompile" (in the Precompile folder) at build-time to generate
    a serialization assembly (this also needs to be referenced and deployed from you application).

    Additional:

    Note that each framework contains 3 files:

    - protobuf-net.dll  the library itself
    - protobuf-net.xml  intellisense xml, used by thre IDE when developing
    - protobuf-net.pdb  debugging symbols, useful when debugging

    Of these - the only one you **need** to deploy is the dll; the pdb may be useful for investigating crash reports. The
    xml is used only by the IDE.

    Folders:

    cf20         compact framework 2.0
    cf35         compact framework 3.5
    ios          iPad/iPod/iPhone via MonoTouch
    net11        regular .NET 1.1 (excluded generics)
    net20        regular .NET 2.0 (excludes WCF hooks)
    net30        regular .NET 3.0 or above (including 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, ...)
    netcore45    windows store apps / windows runtime 4.5
    portable     portable class library (phone 7, xna, silverlight)
    sl4          silverlight 4 or above
    wp71         windows phone 7.1
    unity        specific to unity (avoids missing "interlocked" methods)

    License:

    The full license is shown separately, but boils down to "do what you like with it, don't sue me,
    don't blame me if it goes horribly wrong, don't claim you wrote protobuf-net"

    Finally:

    All feedback welcome.
```

I want to us it with unity, the unity folder or most of the other folders listed including 'full' dont seem to exist... Am I missing something very fundamental here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is not updated, but you can still download version **r668**, which contains the unity folder